# Accessing the index of n-dimensional array among m-dimensional array (n<m) java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

To simplify the context, Let's say we have a 2D array in Java and we need to get the index of given 1D array. Is there any cleaner way of doing the same? The size of my array was pretty small (3 x 8), So I managed to brute force the elements using a for loop and got the index, But what if the size of array is large enough? For my purpose I used the following code:

```
private int getIndex(double[][] centerArrayOriginal, double[] row){
        double[] currRow;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<centerArrayOriginal.length;i++){
            currRow = centerArrayOriginal[i];
            if ((currRow[0] == row[0]) && (currRow[1] == row[1]) && (currRow[2] == row[2])){
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Obviously this is not the most cleaner way of doing the same, I tried using an `ArrayList` of `double[]` elements and used `.indexOf()` method, but it always returned `-1`.

Comment: what happens if there were 2 such rows?

Comment: @Palcente In the cases I am using, there won't be any redundant rows, But I would prefer the answer which returns me all the satisfying indices (if someone in future stumbles upon the same issue) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to search for a given row within an array, I don't see an alternative to "brute-forcing". However, as you are working with `double` arrays, it should be noted that because of rounding errors, the row-finding algorithm may not work if the `row` 1D array comes from e.g. a calculation result. You should only assume reliable results when the data for both `centerArrayOriginal` and `row` consist of `double` literals (constants).

Anyways, here is a solution that uses two nested for-loops for finding the row from a 2D array of arbitrary size:

```
 private static int getIndex(double[][] centerArrayOriginal, double[] row) {

    for (int i = 0; i < centerArrayOriginal.length; i++) {
        double[] currRow = centerArrayOriginal[i];

        if (currRow.length != row.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "The size of the input row (%d) does not "
                            + "match the size of the rows in the array (%d)",
                    row.length, currRow.length));
        }

        boolean allElementsEqual = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            if (currRow[j] != row[j]) {
                allElementsEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allElementsEqual) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Code for testing:

```
double[][] data = new double[][] 
        {
            { 1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d },
            { 4.0d, 5.0d, 6.0d },
            { 7.0d, 8.0d, 9.0d } 
        };
double[] test = new double[] {4.0d, 5.0d, 6.0d};
System.out.println(getIndex(data, test));
```

prints out

```
1
```

Comment: @njzk2, not sure what you mean with that comment.